# Session.getfiles() not working correctly - Powershell

Tags: powershell, winscp-net

Trying to run the following script. Connect to a ftp / sftp server and get the files from a remotepath to a localpath

Since there are a list of sources and destinations, I decided to create a csv file and pass the value using $*.Source and $*.Destination

Session.getfiles ()  seems to not be working when I import my csv file.
But if I hard code the path, it seems to work.

```
$session.GetFiles("c:\source\test", "c:\destination\", $False, $transferOptions)
```

Goal: Script reads the list of Sources and move files according to its destination. Also go back to  a # amount of days and downdload the latest file -

Error: "No such File"  or "cant get attributes of file"

```
try{
  Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"
  # Setup session options
  $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
  Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::sftp
  HostName = "xxxxx"
  UserName = "xxxxr"
  Password = "xxxxxxx"
  PortNumber="xx"
  FTPMode="Active"
 GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnySshHostKey = $true

}
$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
try
{
    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)
    # Download files
    $transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
    $transferOptions.TransferMode = [WinSCP.TransferMode]::Binary

 Import-Csv -Path "C:\movefiles.csv" -ErrorAction Stop 
    $transferResult =
        $session.GetFiles($_.Source, $_.Destination, $False, $transferOptions)
    # Throw on any error
    $transferResult.Check()
    # Print results
    foreach ($transfer in $transferResult.Transfers)
    {
        Write-Host "Download of $($transfer.FileName) succeeded"
    }
 }
 finally
 {
    # Disconnect, clean up
    $session.Dispose()
 }
#exit 0
}
catch
{
  Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
  #exit 1
}
```

Comment: Show us a log file – `$session.SessionLogPath = "C:\some\path\winscp.log"` – before `$session.Open`.

Answer (score -1):

By commenting the line out

```
 $transferresult.check()
```

Script seems to work. But still missing how to get only new files